# how can I change the color of a navbar's links' color for specific class or section of HTML?

Tags: html, css, colors, nav

I would appreciate your help, I have an HTML document, with a simple sticky header and white links.  The website has alternating dark background sections and light background sections.  I am trying to have a white navbar for the dark sections and a dark navbar for the light sections (just targeting the text color of the links).  If I dont change the colors, then the white text is not visible on the light colored pages. Thanks in advance.

```css
    a  {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    
    .container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 2.4rem;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 122.5rem;
    }
    
    
    .navbar {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        height: 8rem;
    }
    
    .nav-list {
        list-style: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: $black;
        padding: 4.4rem;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
        z-index: 1;
      
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s;
    }
    /* Media Queries : Tablet */
    
    @media screen and (min-width: $media-m) {
        .nav-list {
            position: fixed;
            width: initial;
            height: initial;
            background-color: transparent;
            padding: 1rem;
            justify-content: initial;
            flex-direction: row;
            transform: initial;
            transition: initial;
            }
        
        .nav-link {
            margin-left: 4rem;
            transition: all 0.1s;
        }
        .menu-toggle {
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
<div id= "mobilSidenav" class="container">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="img/Logo.png" alt="logo" srcset="img/logo.svg">
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li>
        <a class="nav-link nav_fontsize active link" href="dasCafe.html">das Cafe</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="nav-link nav_fontsize link" href="dieHerkunft.html">Herkunft</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="nav-link nav_fontsize link" href="#">Shop</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="nav-link nav_fontsize link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="menu-toggle">
      <div class="hamburger">
      </div>
    </div>      
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: start by clearly defining for which SCENARIO(s) you want the colour change to happen and then for which ELEMENT(s).

Comment: The following sections are classed as either with a dark background (class ="bg_dark")or a light background  (class ="bg_light").  The dark background gets  white nav links in the sticky header, while the light background sections get black colored a links. Thanks in advance.

<section id="landing_page" class="bg_dark">
    </section>

  <section id="kaffee_sorten" class="bg_dark">
</section>

  <section id="cafe" class="bg_light">

Comment: can you show us a visual example or demo of what the intended end result should look like? it can be a simple sketch